# Algorithm implemented with openCL working till size exceeds 768

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I've implemented sorting algorithm using openCL. Its using one work group per array to sort (arrays are connected in __global float *array, all have the same size). 
Im testing results using 200 random arrays and result are deterministic.

With one parameter, its working correctly till array size exceeds of array 768
With two parameters, its working correctly till arrays size exceeds 768
With three parameters, its working correctly till arrays size exceeds 317

What could be the reason of correct processing of just 768 (CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE returns 1024 elements). Is it some memory constraints? What is the best way of invastigation such issue?

[Gpu specs (4th answer):](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/521502/gt650m-a-kepler-part-/])

Kernel code below:

```
__kernel void assort(
__global float *array,
__local float *currentOutput,
__local float *stimulations,
__local int *noOfValuesAdded,
__local float *addedValue,
__local float *positionToInsert,
__local int *activatedIdx,
__local float *range,
int size
)   {

int id = get_local_id(0);
int gid = get_group_id(0);

if (id == 0) 
{
    if (array[gid*size]<array[gid*size+1]) 
    {
        currentOutput[0] = array[gid*size];
        currentOutput[1] = array[gid*size + 1];
    }
    else
    {
        currentOutput[1] = array[gid*size];
        currentOutput[0] = array[gid*size + 1];
    }
    noOfValuesAdded[0] = 2;
}
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

for (int i = 2; i < size; i++) 
{
    int maxIdx = noOfValuesAdded[0] - 1;

    if (id == 0) 
    {
        addedValue[0] = array[gid*size + i];
        positionToInsert[0] = -100.0f;
        activatedIdx[0] = -2;
        range[0] = currentOutput[maxIdx] - currentOutput[0];
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if (id < noOfValuesAdded[0]) 
    {
        if (id == 0) 
        {
            stimulations[id] = (currentOutput[maxIdx] - addedValue[0]) / range[0];

            float stimulation = stimulations[id];

            if ( fabs(stimulation - 1.0f) < 0.000001)
                    activatedIdx[0] = 0;
            else if (stimulation > 1.0f)
               { 
                   activatedIdx[0] = -1;
               }
        }
        else if (id == maxIdx) 
        {
            stimulations[maxIdx] = (addedValue[0] - currentOutput[0]) / range[0];

            float stimulations = (addedValue[0] - currentOutput[0]) / range[0];

            if ( fabs(stimulations - 1.0f) < 0.000001 ) 
              activatedIdx[0] = maxIdx;
            else 
                if (stimulations > 1)
                   activatedIdx[0] = maxIdx + 1;
       }
       else 
       {
                stimulations[id] = 1.0f - (fabs((currentOutput[id] - addedValue[0])) / range[0]);

                if ( fabs(stimulations[id] - 1.0f) < 0.000001) 
                    activatedIdx[0] = id;
       }
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if (activatedIdx[0] == -2 && id < noOfValuesAdded[0]) 
    {
        if (noOfValuesAdded[0] == 2)
        {
            positionToInsert[0] = 0.9f;
        }
        else if (id != 0 && 
                 id != maxIdx &&
                 stimulations[id] >= stimulations[(id - 1)] &&
                 stimulations[id] >= stimulations[(id + 1)] ) 
                {
                    if ((1.0f - (fabs(currentOutput[(id - 1)] - currentOutput[id]) / range[0]) ) < stimulations[(id - 1)])
                        positionToInsert[0] = (float)id - 0.1f;
                    else
                        positionToInsert[0] = (float)id + 0.9f;
                }
    }

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if (activatedIdx[0] == -2) 
    {
        if (id == 0 && positionToInsert[0] < -90.0f) // default value maintained
        {
            if (stimulations[0] > stimulations[1])
                positionToInsert[0] = 0.9f;
            else
                positionToInsert[0] = (float)maxIdx - 0.1f;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if (activatedIdx[0] == -1)
            positionToInsert[0] = -0.1f;
        else if (activatedIdx[0] == (maxIdx + 1)) 
        {
            positionToInsert[0] = (float)maxIdx + 0.9f;
        }
        else 
        {
            currentOutput[activatedIdx[0]] = addedValue[0];
        }
    }

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if (positionToInsert[0] > -50.0f) // default value changed
    {
        float temp = 0.0f;
        if ((float)id>positionToInsert[0]) 
        {
            temp = currentOutput[id];
            currentOutput[id + 1] = temp;
        }
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        if ((float)id > positionToInsert[0]) 
        {
            temp = currentOutput[id];
        }

        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        if (id == round(positionToInsert[0])) 
        {
            currentOutput[id] = addedValue[0];
            noOfValuesAdded[0] = noOfValuesAdded[0] + 1;
        }
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
}

barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

array[gid*size + id] = currentOutput[id];

return;
}
```

Comment: How about `barriers` inside `if (positionToInsert[0] > -50.0f)`? In my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41033893/4899330) I already told you that all work items have to meet all barriers. Until this is fixed don't expect your code to work properly.

Comment: @doqtor positionToInsert is the same for every work group item (before this place we have synchronization barrier) so I assumed all work items will hit barrier or ignore it ("If barrier is inside a conditional statement, then all work-items must enter the conditional if any work-item enters the conditional statement and executes the barrier").  Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I haven't noticed that this is actually all work items accessing the same array item value, you can ignore my previous comment. Another thing, are you sure that there isn't any race condition issue when modifying `activatedIdx[0]` and `positionToInsert[0]`? Also is `size` equal to number of work items in the work group?

Comment: @doqtor Yes, size is equal to number of items in the work group. I could propably replace it with get_local_size(). If there is no hardware constraints, data race seems to be logical assumption. But, there should be only one work item in group per iteration thats is modyfing those values, so its higly unlikely. I will try to look into this more deeply.